# Reaction of 1,3 Butadiene with HBr in the presence of peroxides

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I have learnt that the reaction of 1,3 Butadiene with HBr depends on the temperature as the temperature determines whether the reaction is under kinectic control or thermodynamic control. I believe that this is due to the hybrid nature of the carbocation and relative stabilities of the products. Will the same effects take place in the presence of peroxides? (because the allylic radical is also resonance stabilized)